# Watermark coming on whole image Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I want to place the watermark on the bottom right of the picture. But, in some mobiles it is coming perfectly and in some mobile phones, the watermark is coming on the whole image.

Here is my code:

```
rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage, 0, 0,
                            loadedImage.getWidth(), loadedImage.getHeight(),
                            rotateMatrix, false);

                    int w = rotatedBitmap.getWidth();
                    int h = rotatedBitmap.getHeight();
                    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, rotatedBitmap.getConfig());
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(rotatedBitmap, 0, 0, null);

                    Bitmap waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.watermark2);
                int ww = waterMark.getWidth();
                int hh = waterMark.getHeight();
                    canvas.drawBitmap(waterMark,(w-ww),(h-hh), null);
```

EDIT: Here are the screenshots of the result. In second picture, the watermark is coming perfectly and in first picture, it is coming on the whole picture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any Screenshot please

Comment: Scale the watermark depending on the size of the target image.

Comment: @PratikButani I have added the screenshots

Comment: What is `w` , `ww`, `h`, `hh`?

Comment: @PratikButani w and h is the width and height of the image and ww and hh is the width and height of the watermark. You can see it in the code

Comment: Do you have different versions of R.drawable.watermark2 for different screen densities?

Comment: @mvai no, I have only inserted one picture in the drawable folder for all the screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

Make use of aspect ratio. Calculate aspect ratio of device and accordingly calculate appropriate size for your water mark.

**How to calculate aspect ratio?**

Check for width and height of screen whichever is bigger divide it by smaller one
example:

`if(screen_width > screen_height){
         aspectRatio = screen_width/screen_height
  }else{
         aspectRatio = screen_height/screen_width
  }`

now that you have calculated aspect ratio multiply it with size of you water mark and scale it accordingly.

like:

float ww = watermark.getWidth()*aspectRatio;
float wh = watermark.getHeight()*aspectRatio;

and use these values.

Hope this helps...

Comment: The same problem is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

**Just Give ratio and you go to go,try changing ratio values that best fit for your src bitmap .**

- Embeds an image watermark over a source image to produce a
  watermarked one.
- @param source The source image where watermark should be placed
- @param ratio A float value < 1 to give the ratio of watermark's
  height to image's   height,
- try changing this from 0.20 to 0.60 to obtain right results

  ```
  public static Bitmap addWatermark(Context context, Bitmap source, float ratio) 
  {
   Canvas canvas;
   Paint paint;
   Bitmap bmp;
   Matrix matrix;
   RectF r;

   int width, height;
   float scale;

   Bitmap waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.watermark3x);

   width = source.getWidth();
   height = source.getHeight();

   // Create the new bitmap
   bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);

   // Copy the original bitmap into the new one
   canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
   canvas.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, paint);

   // Scale the watermark to be approximately to the ratio given of the source image height
   scale = (float) (((float) height * ratio) / (float) waterMark.getHeight());

   // Create the matrix
   matrix = new Matrix();
   matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

   // Determine the post-scaled size of the watermark
   r = new RectF(0, 0, waterMark.getWidth(), waterMark.getHeight());
   matrix.mapRect(r);

   // Move the watermark to the bottom right corner
   matrix.postTranslate(width - r.width(), height - r.height());

    // Move the watermark to the bottom left corner
    // matrix.postTranslate(0 , height - r.height());

    // Move the watermark to the top-left corner
    // matrix.postTranslate(0 ,0);

    // Move the watermark to the top right corner
    // matrix.postTranslate(width - r.width(), 0l̥);


   // Draw the watermark
   canvas.drawBitmap(waterMark, matrix, paint);

   return bmp;
  }
  ```